# Which Namespace or Nuget Binding BlobProperties in Azure Functions V3

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Is there a Nuget/Assembly/Library that will allow me to bind BlobProperties for .NET Core Azure 3.x Functions, in both a local environment and in an Azure environment?

I have an Azure Function running on .NET Core 3 with a signature that looks like this:

```
public async Task DoFunctionWork([BlobTrigger("path/to/{blobName}")] Stream blobStream, 
**Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.BlobProperties Properties**)
{
    //Function Body....
}
```

The problem is with the Properties parameter. If run locally, it can only be resolved if I prefix the BlobProperties parameter with the Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob namespace as above. In Azure, it never seems to work. When it fails - on either Azure or locally - I get one of the following messages:

```
Can't bind properties to type 'Azure.Storage.Blob.Properties' or Can't bind properties to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.Properties'
```

Has anyone encountered this before? How did you solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is because, there is a version mismatch between what your SDK requires and what you have installed.

For instance, if you are using 3.0.9 version of Function SDK, then you might have installed `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` other than `(>= 3.0.0 && < 3.1.0)` versions.

- [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/)
- [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 4.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage)

Comment: Marking as correct. Weirdly enough I had 2 references to the SDK, 3.0.0 and 3.0.10. in my project, and also two versions of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage in my project (3.x and 4.x). No idea how that actually happened, but the local environment managed the situation well, but Azure did not.  Corrected the project file, and all is good now. Thanks singhh-msft.